# Is there a way to override a material when working with UVs?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Basically I want a UV-Grid image showing on the model without having to touch the material of the object. Whatever image I chose in the UV-Editor should be mapped to the object while I'm in edit mode. Is that possible? I'm running 2.8 now.
Thanks

Comment: not possible, stupid question, or rtfm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe **it's not currently possible** (as of December 2018) with a simple UI toggle. A UV checker overlay that doesn't affect the materials [is one of the most loved features proposed by the community](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Dpcbbc/better-uv-visualization-with-improved-random-color), but still not implemented.

[image]

<sup>*mockup by Xuri Greer*</sup>

I think that we will see this feature in the (very) near future, since it's known that the devs have discussed it already.

---

A workflow I normally use is:

- Add a Shader editor to the "UV Editing" workspace, and switch the Viewport to LookDev

  [image]
- Make your actual material single user and create a different "Diagnostic material" with a textured Emission shader (add a UVMap input if it's not unique)

  [image]
- When you change the texture in the editor, update the material too

  [image]

After having this set up, it's just a matter of one more click each time you switch.

(You may prefer using the "Node Wrangler addon"'s preview feature instead of a whole new material)